# Python, AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'button_vln'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have been working with Pyqt5 to create a View and am now looking to get everything working using a Controller-class. However I guess I messed up the implementation of the view as it does not work when starting the controller.
I found examples which showed my how to do it, but i am completely new to python so i don´t really understand how to implement it.

Py_Controller.py

```
from typing import ChainMap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from Py_View import View
#from data_conversion.model.Configuration import Configuration

import sys


class Controller:
    def __init__(self):
     #   self.configuration = Configuration()
        self.view = View()

#Buttons für Stacked Widget
        self.view.button_vln.clicked.connect(self.show_vln)
        self.view.button_ntp.clicked.connect(self.show_ntp)
        self.view.button_thrchnnl.clicked.connect(self.show_thrchnnl)
        self.view.button_dfltrt.clicked.connect(self.show_dfltrt)
        self.view.button_stp.clicked.connect(self.show_stp)
        self.view.button_dhcpsnppng.clicked.connect(self.show_dhcpsnppng)
        self.view.button_rtgrd.clicked.connect(self.show_rtgrd)
        self.view.button_sr.clicked.connect(self.show_sr)
    
#Funktionalitäten Benutzerinteraktionen   
        self.view.button_exportieren.clicked.connect(self.action_exportieren)    
        self.view.button_speichern.clicked.connect(self.action_speichern)    
        self.view.button_oeffnen.clicked.connect(self.action_oeffnen)    
        self.view.button_hinzufuegen.clicked.connect(self.action_hinzufuegen)    
        self.view.combo_hersteller.clicked.connect(self.action_hersteller)    
        self.view.text_host.clicked.connect(self.action_host)    

#Method - Funktionalitäten Benutzerinteraktionen 
#Return 0 gegen exception austauschen, Aufgrund von "Zaht mi grod nd" wurde die Aufgabe auf später verschoben
        def action_exportieren(self):
            return 0
        def action_speichern(self):
            return 0
        def action_oeffnen(self):
            return 0
        def action_hinzufuegen(self):
            return 0
        def action_hersteller(self):
            return 0
        def action_host(self):
            return 0
            

#Method - show Stacked widget
    def show_vln(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_vln)
    def show_ntp(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_ntp)
    def show_thrchnnl(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_thrchnnl)
    def show_dfltrt(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_dfltrt)
    def show_stp(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_stp)
    def show_dhcpsnppng(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_dhcpsnppng)
    def show_rtgrd(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_rtgrd)
    def show_sr(self):
        self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_sr)
        

#startview - übernimmt die Pyqt5-View in das MVC
    def startview(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.view.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


   
        

#Main - wird beim Programmaufruf ausgeführt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    controller = Controller()
    print('started')
    
    controller.startview()


    #sys.exit(Controller().run())

    #if __name__ == "__main__":
     #   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      #  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
       # ui = View()
        #ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        #MainWindow.show()
        #sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Py_View

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class View:
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
       MainWindow.resize(1000, 700)
       MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 700))
...
   #Tooltips Arp Protection
       self.interfaceids2.setToolTip("<font color=black>Die von der Konfiguration betroffenen Interfaces, mit , von einander getrennt</font>")
       self.encapsulationtype.setToolTip("<font color=black>Gibt den Verkapselungstyp für eine Schnittstelle nach Netzwerktyp an, Ethernet, FDDI, Frame Relay und Token Ring</font>")
       #Tooltips für Benutzer
       self.hostname.setToolTip("<font color=black>Name mit welchem der Host im Netzerk identifiziert werden kann</font>")
       self.passwort.setToolTip("<font color=black>Passwort zur Sicherung der Bearbeitungsberechtigung des Hosts</font>")
      

       
if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   ui = View()
   ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   MainWindow.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I can`t paste my View.py, because of character limitation.  It`s been made with qt-designer and i double checked the variables used, so there shouldn`t be a problem regarding the view.

Edited Py_Controller

```
from typing import ChainMap

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from Py_View import View
from Py_Model import Model
import sys


class Controller(QApplication):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Controller, self).__init__()
       
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
       self.ui = View()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)

#Buttons für Stacked Widget
       self.view.button_vln.clicked.connect(self.show_vln)
       self.view.button_ntp.clicked.connect(self.show_ntp)
       self.view.button_thrchnnl.clicked.connect(self.show_thrchnnl)
       self.view.button_dfltrt.clicked.connect(self.show_dfltrt)
       self.view.button_stp.clicked.connect(self.show_stp)
       self.view.button_dhcpsnppng.clicked.connect(self.show_dhcpsnppng)
       self.view.button_rtgrd.clicked.connect(self.show_rtgrd)
       self.view.button_sr.clicked.connect(self.show_sr)

#Funktionalitäten Benutzerinteraktionen
       self.view.button_exportieren.clicked.connect(self.action_exportieren)
       self.view.button_speichern.clicked.connect(self.action_speichern)
       self.view.button_oeffnen.clicked.connect(self.action_oeffnen)
       self.view.button_hinzufuegen.clicked.connect(self.action_hinzufuegen)
       self.view.combo_hersteller.clicked.connect(self.action_hersteller)
       self.view.text_host.clicked.connect(self.action_host)

#Method - Funktionalitäten Benutzerinteraktionen
#Return 0 gegen exception austauschen, Aufgrund von "Zaht mi grod nd" wurde die Aufgabe auf später verschoben
       def action_exportieren(self):
           return 0
       def action_speichern(self):
           return 0
       def action_oeffnen(self):
           return 0
       def action_hinzufuegen(self):
           return 0
       def action_hersteller(self):
           return 0
       def action_host(self):
           return 0
           

#Method - show Stacked widget
   def show_vln(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_vln)
   def show_ntp(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_ntp)
   def show_thrchnnl(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_thrchnnl)
   def show_dfltrt(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_dfltrt)
   def show_stp(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_stp)
   def show_dhcpsnppng(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_dhcpsnppng)
   def show_rtgrd(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_rtgrd)
   def show_sr(self):
       self.view.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.view.stack_sr)
       

#startview - übernimmt die Pyqt5-View in das MVC


#Main - wird beim Programmaufruf ausgeführt
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print('started')
```

Comment: Is `View` a class in a pyuic generated file? If that's so, you're using it wrong: that's a basic python object class, you're not expected to use it alone, but to "install" it on an actual QWidget. Please read the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: I created View iwth QtDesigner. I am a complete noob so i dont understand what you mean wit "using it alone". I have edited my Post, to show the beginning and the end of the View File.

Comment: Read the link in my first comment.

Comment: Yeah, sry for my stupid question. Well i don´t think i understood it completetly, I edited my Question based on what i have read. It prints the "started" message, but no window pops up.

Comment: Before implementing your code, I suggest you to start with a basic example and follow what's explained in that link, so that you can understand how it works. Also, your indentation of the `action_...` functions is wrong, and remember that returned values for functions connected to signals are ignored.

Comment: I read that link carefully, however my example is  a bit different, i am not using a .ui file and i do not get how i can initialize my Controller to perform its  `def __init__(self):`

Comment: I know that your example is different, that's why you need to understand how the basic system works before applying it to your case. If you don't understand the basics, you cannot do the rest. For instance, you're subclassing from QApplication, which is ***not*** a widget, so you cannot use `setupUi(self)`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).